# NPM - dependencies require package in multiple versions, but only one version is installed

Tags: node.js, npm

After `npm install` on clean environment, I get following problem with `b` package:

```
npm ls b   

a@2.0.6
├── b@3.0.0
├─┬ c@3.0.1
│ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY b@^1.0.0
└─┬ d@4.1.1
  └─┬ c@2.1.0
    └── UNMET DEPENDENCY b@^1.0.0

npm ERR! missing: b@^1.0.0, required by c@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: b@^1.0.0, required by c@2.1.0
```

This obviously causes errors, as package `c` needs `b@^1.0.0`, but receives `b@3.0.0`.

I struggled to force npm to install both versions as if they were different packages. Tried going through npm docs, package-locks, and shinkwrap, but with no success. How can I solve this problem?

Environment info:

```
OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
npm: 6.10
node: v8.8.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Playing around I noticed, that a lot of packages had UNMET DEPENDENCY. Following procedure fixed the problem:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

After cleaning npm cache the issue is completely resolved:

```
a@2.0.6
├── b@3.0.0
├─┬ c@3.0.1
│ └── b@^1.0.0
└─┬ d@4.1.1
  └─┬ c@2.1.0
    └── b@^1.0.0
```

Strange bug.